# Centos -bash process high cpu usage

Tags: linux, centos, cpu-usage

I have a centos 8 OS. There is some process wth `-bash`  command with high cpu usage that has fully usage 4 cores of 8 cores. When I kill these processes or restart the server the command automatically run and make cpu usage high.
How can I detect what problem is?

[image: monitoring cpu usage with htop]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: That is almost certainly a malware process falsely claiming to be Bash, probably crypto mining. I can see you rebooted about 90 minutes ago. If this was on my laptop, I would shut down immediately, and reboot from my Live DVD to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a malware process falsely claiming to be Bash. I find a ‍‍`test` directory in `/tmp` that has a bash script to running unknown scripts. I remove this script and the process don't run again. I don't know how this malware access the server. I will reinstall OS.